# How to implement multiple PanGestures (Draggable views)?

Tags: swift, autolayout, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to have several objects that I can drag and drop.

Here's my code for moving one object (with lot of help from @vacawama):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var panView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var panViewCenterX: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var panViewCenterY: NSLayoutConstraint!

let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    panRec.addTarget(self, action: "draggedView:")
    panView.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
    var translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

    panViewCenterY.constant += translation.y
    panViewCenterX.constant += translation.x

    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}   

}
```

I want to have more objects in my project:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var panView2: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var panView3: UIView!
 @IBOutlet weak var panView4: UIView!
 ...
```

So, what is the easiest way to implement this in such way that I can have multiple  `panView` which I can move independently around (one at the time)?

Comment: Just do it. What's the problem?

Comment: My problem is that I don't fully understand what I'm actually doing (that's why I'm posting here). Here's my "understanding": I detect a PanGesture with `panRec` and passes that gesture to `func draggedView` and there I set the new location. But what exactly does `panView.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)`. Or is it the other way around? I hoped there was a way where I could have  one `panRec` and test with i.e switch statement whether it was `panView1` or `panView2` or `panView3` etc.. and then set the location accordingly.

Comment: I've gone through so many examples and tut's that I'm soon to give up... Punching me with "-1" doesn't really help ;-)

Comment: Don't give up! I have an idea about how to do this in an easier way.  It involves a subclass of UIView (call it DraggableView) that keeps track of its own constraints.  It involves creating constraints in code instead of in Interface Builder.  I won't be able to get to this for 12 hours though, so you'll have to be patient unless someone else answers.

Comment: I'll keep in there and reading some more while I'm waiting ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using *Auto Layout*, you shouldn't just move a view by altering its center.  Anything that causes *Auto Layout* to run will move your view back to its original position.

Here is an implementation of a new class called `DraggableView` that works with *Auto Layout* to provide views that can be dragged.  It creates constraints in code for the width, height, X position, and Y position of the view.  It uses its own `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to allow the view to be dragged.

*DraggableView.swift* can be dropped into any project that needs draggable views.  Take a look at *ViewController.swift* below to see how easy it is to use.

**DraggableView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class DraggableView: UIView {
    let superView: UIView!
    let xPosConstraint:  NSLayoutConstraint!
    let yPosConstraint:  NSLayoutConstraint!
    var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        get {
            return [xPosConstraint, yPosConstraint]
        }
    }

    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, color: UIColor, superView: UIView) {
        super.init()

        self.superView = superView

        self.backgroundColor = color

        self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "draggedView:")
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: width)
        self.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: height)
        self.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

        xPosConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: x)

        yPosConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: y)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func moveByDeltaX(deltaX: CGFloat, deltaY: CGFloat) {
        xPosConstraint.constant += deltaX
        yPosConstraint.constant += deltaY
    }

    func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if let dragView = sender.view as? DraggableView {
            superView.bringSubviewToFront(dragView)
            var translation = sender.translationInView(superView)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: superView)
            dragView.moveByDeltaX(translation.x, deltaY: translation.y)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let dragView1 = DraggableView(width: 75, height: 75, x: 50, y: 50,
            color: UIColor.redColor(), superView: self.view)
        self.view.addSubview(dragView1)
        self.view.addConstraints(dragView1.constraints)

        let dragView2 = DraggableView(width: 100, height: 100, x: 150, y: 50,
            color: UIColor.blueColor(), superView: self.view)
        self.view.addSubview(dragView2)
        self.view.addConstraints(dragView2.constraints)

        let dragView3 = DraggableView(width: 125, height: 125, x: 100, y: 175,
            color: UIColor.greenColor(), superView: self.view)
        self.view.addSubview(dragView3)
        self.view.addConstraints(dragView3.constraints)
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is a version of **DraggableView.swift** that supports images as a subview.

```
import UIKit

class DraggableView: UIView {
    let superView: UIView!
    let xPosConstraint:  NSLayoutConstraint!
    let yPosConstraint:  NSLayoutConstraint!
    var constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        get {
            return [xPosConstraint, yPosConstraint]
        }
    }

    init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, color: UIColor, superView: UIView, imageToUse: String? = nil, contentMode: UIViewContentMode = .ScaleAspectFill) {
        super.init()

        self.superView = superView

        self.backgroundColor = color

        self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "draggedView:")
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: width)
        self.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: height)
        self.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

        xPosConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: x)

        yPosConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: superView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: y)

        if imageToUse != nil {
            if let image = UIImage(named: imageToUse!) {
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
                imageView.contentMode = contentMode
                imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                imageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
                self.addSubview(imageView)
                self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
                self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
                self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
                self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
            }
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func moveByDeltaX(deltaX: CGFloat, deltaY: CGFloat) {
        xPosConstraint.constant += deltaX
        yPosConstraint.constant += deltaY
    }

    func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if let dragView = sender.view as? DraggableView {
            superView.bringSubviewToFront(dragView)
            var translation = sender.translationInView(superView)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: superView)
            dragView.moveByDeltaX(translation.x, deltaY: translation.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is clever but kind of unnecessary. If a view is going to be draggable, it isn't suitable for being positioned by autolayout. So just take it out of autolayout. It is perfectly reasonable / legal for one or two special views not to be subject to autolayout in the midst of an interface that does use autolayout.

Comment: How do you "take a view out of autolayout"?

Comment: @matt, this is a follow up question to one the OP asked earlier.  In that one, he was updating a `UILabel` and his dragged views stopped working because of Auto Layout.  He said he wanted Auto Layout so that is why I headed down this path.  I don't know how to disable Auto Layout for a single view, just for a Storyboard or XIB.

Comment: I'm not criticizing! I'm just saying that in many situations this might be overkill. Let's say we've got a kind of puzzle game with some buttons at the top and an area with some draggable views in the middle. Then it probably makes sense for the draggable views not to participate in autolayout. The fact that autolayout and non-autolayout views can be combined in the same interface doesn't occur to people sometimes; that's why I'm pointing it out.

Comment: I don't think you're criticising. I don't understand how to make the draggable views not participate in Auto Layout.

Comment: Oh. Well, there are lots of ways. Create them in code and stick them into the interface; or, if they must be created in a nib / storyboard, use a different nib / storyboard, turn off autolayout for _that_ nib / storyboard, and load it and stick them into the interface; or, if they must be created in the same storyboard as everything else, apply placeholder constraints and then turn off their `translates...` in code.

Comment: If you're not using autolayout, is it most safe to do all placement ref's from center of screen, to be absolutely sure nothing ends up outside the screen?

Comment: You don't need to do placement relative to the center of the screen, but if you want the subview to be entirely on screen you need to keep the center.x of the subview between (0.5*subview.frame.width) at the minimum and (view.bounds.width - 0.5*subview.frame.width) at the maximum.  Likewise, keep center.y between (0.5*subview.frame.height) and (view.bounds.height - 0.5*subview.frame.height).

Comment: That makes sense!! Thanx! Just to follow up; if no using autolayout, will the `bounds`still be the size of the unit you are running on? With other words, If I turn of Autolayout and choose iPhone4 while setting up my storyboard and then deploy it to an iPad, the `bounds` will adapt accordingly?

Comment: Yes, the bounds will adapt.  That is why you use it instead of hard coded numbers.

Comment: Perfect!! to be able to avoid such questions in the future, could you please point me in the right direction to where I find such information? Tried to look in "Xcode Overview" and searched the "iOS Developer Library" without luck :-o Guess this info is somewhere...

Comment: There is a lot of good info out there, but most of it is in Objective-C.  It would be beneficial for you to learn the Objective-C way as well.  I highly recommend the Stanford course on iTunes U: https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550.  I also recommend the Big Nerd Ranch book as an introductory book, and raywenderlich.com for tutorials.

Comment: Thanx! Already used raywenderlich.com which is good! Will look into  the others you recommend as well!

Comment: I've added some values to pass in your example, to be able to view an image in the IUView object that is created. That works fine, but I'm not able to resize the image I pass to the 'DraggableView'. Here's what I've done, which works: added 'let scaledImage: UIImage!' at the top. In the 'init' where all values are "received", I've added 'imageToUse: String'. Then I do the following, which works: 'scaledImage = UIImage(named: imageToUse)' and then 'self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: scaledImage!)'. But I'm not able to do i.e 'scaledImage.size.width = width'... why?

Comment: Check out the update.  I added images to the draggable view.  It uses constraints to keep the image scaled to the view.

Comment: You're good! thanx! After reading some more I'm wondering if this is the right way for me... What I'm planning to do is to detect when these auto-generated views are colliding (or boundaries touches). I also want to add some physics to them.. do you think it's better to do that in sprite kit an make each object a sprite kite node? or can I have some part of my project as is and other "scenes" in sprite kit?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like Sprite Kit would be the way to go.  Look at Ray Wenderlich's book iOS Games by Tutorials 2nd Edition (you can buy the PDF from raywenderlich.com).  The 2nd Edition has been updated for iOS 8 and Swift.

Comment: Ok, thanx... I'll try to get hold of that one.. Also tried to go through some tut's (without programming myself), but couldn't find anywhere where they conclude about using PanGesture in sprite, in the same way you explained...

Comment: Anyway! You've been a great helper!!!! One quick, and final thought: for my app, there will be at the beginning screen a selection of options. one of the options will be the "game" module, but the others will be a place where the user can enter words (by keyboard) into several lists. Once that's done, the game can be entered and those words will be cut into letters which have to be moved around... So, I guess what I want is a storyboard with several view controllers where one (or more) of them acts as "scene" (using sprite-kit). Is that possible?

Comment: I feel like that should be possible but I've never done that myself. Search SO for questions about combining Sprite Kit scenes with normal view controllers. If you don't find anything, post a new question explaining in detail what you're trying to accomplish. Someone might have even implemented a whole keyboard in Sprite Kit.

Comment: I tried it and it worked :-D Therefore I'll keep on working with the code you helped with me...

Comment: Now I'm able to make multiple objects which I can move around. I'm also able to detect state.Ended, but I'm not able to do much with the object I'm moving. Here's the code I've added 'if' statement in the 'func draggedView': 'if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
                if yPosConstraint.constant > 300 {
                    println("under")
                }
                else {
                    println("y: \(yPosConstraint.constant)")
                }
            }' This works, but how do I get to change properties like background color of the object??

Comment: False alarm!!! For some reason my autocompletion stopped working :-o which made everything to male-functioning :-D Anyway, fixed now, so all is good...

Comment: Sorry for this, but one more question: I've copied the `DraggableView` and removed the _gesture_ part, to generate more objects in my view. That works fine. But, how can I access info about those generated views from the `func draggedView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer)` statement inside the `DraggableView`? I want to check if the one that are dragged and dropped is overlapping the one that is not draggable (which is made from my copied routine). If they overlap, I want to check if it's overlapping the correct object and then change the background color of the static object... any ideas?

Comment: Stack Overflow asks us not to carry on extended conversations in comments.  We crossed that limit over 15+ comments ago.  If you have more questions, it's time to search Stack Overflow or post a new question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way a gesture recognizer works is that you attach it to a view. So if you have multiple views, and you want them to be draggable in the same way, attach a different pan gesture recognizer to each one.

Now let's say you want them all to have the same action handler. No problem. In the action handler, you receive the current gesture recognizer as a parameter. It has a `view` property; that's the view it is attached to! So now you know that that's the view you're moving.

Comment: But in general, don't you think it would be better to _learn_ about gesture recognizers before you use them, so you're not thrashing around and saying "I don't fully understand what I'm actually doing"? For example, I explain them to you here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_gesture_recognizers

Comment: Yes, in general, I agree! I understand the concept of gestures, it's the implementation part I'm struggling with.. I'll keep on reading, thanx for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Finally:

Found this example which explained it in a easy way:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

So, now multiple Pan's are working..

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var boxToMove1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var boxToMove2: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func handlePan(objectToMove:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = objectToMove.translationInView(self.view)
    objectToMove.view!.center = CGPoint(x: objectToMove.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: objectToMove.view!.center.y + translation.y)
    objectToMove.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    println("\(objectToMove.view!.tag)") //Verify correct object received
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I linked up the "Pan Gesture Recognizer" from the "Object library" to each `boxToMove`. Then I linked the "Pan Gesture Recognizer" (both) to my `@IBAction func handlePan`...

This is now working!!!
Finally I understand the way this Gesture Recognizer is working!

What I'm still trying to figure out is how to do all this linking programmatically.. Any idea?