# Multiple pan gestures in SpriteKit scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

I have an `SKScene` with a bunch of nodes (`SKSpriteNode`s, `SKShapeNode`s, etc.) that I'd like to be able to pan *individually* and *simultaneously*. I need to be able to:

- Touch one node and move it around.
- While moving one node, touch multiple other nodes and move them, as well.

If I could add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to each node, for instance, this would be easy. But, as far as I can tell, my only option with a `UIGestureRecognizer` is to add it to the `view` of the `SKScene`. I've implemented this with a single recognizer, and juggling all of the touches and nodes in the recognizer's associated action on my `SKScene` was a bit of a pain. Here's what I did for the recognizer:

```
class MultiplePanGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    var currentTouches: Array<UITouch> = []

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

        for touch in touches {
            currentTouches.append(touch as UITouch)
        }

        state = .Began
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)

        state = .Changed
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)

        removeCancelledOrEndedTouches(touches)
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)

        removeCancelledOrEndedTouches(touches)
    }

    // Add new touches to currentTouches
    func addUntrackedTouchesFromSet(touches: NSSet!) {

        for touch in touches {

            let index = find(currentTouches, touch as UITouch)

            if index == nil {

                currentTouches.append(touch as UITouch)
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove received touches from currentTouches array
    func removeCancelledOrEndedTouches(touches: NSSet!) {

        for touch in touches {
            if let index = find(currentTouches, touch as UITouch) {
                currentTouches.removeAtIndex(index)
            }
        }

        // End the gesture if there are no touches remaining in currentTouches
        if currentTouches.count == 0 {
            state = .Ended
        }
    }

    override func reset() {

        super.reset()

        currentTouches = []
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm just keeping all touches available on the `currentTouches` property of the gesture recognizer so that I can access *all* them in the attached action. This means that I have to juggle what touches hit nodes, etc., in the `SKScene`. Originally, I tried restarting the gesture by setting its state to `.Began` in the gesture recognizer's `touchesBegan:withEvent:`. However, manually resetting the recognizer's state to `.Began` didn't trigger the action, so I was forced to let new touches trigger a `.Changed` state in my recognizer, and then juggle everything back in the action.

For reference, here's the method in my `SKScene` that is added as the recognizer's action:

```
func handleMultiplePan(recognizer: MultiplePanGestureRecognizer) {

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .Began, .Changed:

        // Remove those touches from tracking that are no longer being
        // recognized
        touchNodeMap.prune(recognizer.currentTouches)

        // Iterate over the recognizer's currentTouches
        for touch in recognizer.currentTouches {

            // Is it over a child node of the scene?
            if let node = getChildNodeForTouch(touch) {

                // If so, add it to the touchNodeMap
                touchNodeMap.add(touch, withNode: node)
            }
        }

        // Iterate over currentlyPanningTouches and move nodes accordingly
        for (touch, node) in touchNodeMap {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
            let deltaX = location.x - previousLocation.x
            let deltaY = location.y - previousLocation.y
            node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x + deltaX, node.position.y + deltaY)
        }

        // Get node for most recent touch
        let (_, mostRecentNode) = touchNodeMap.mostRecentTouchAndNode()

        // Remove and re-add it to the scene
        if mostRecentNode != nil {
            mostRecentNode!.removeFromParent()
            addChild(mostRecentNode!)
        }

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

(`touchNodeMap` is simply a `Dictionary` that maps `UITouch`es to `SKNode`s.)

My question is, am I missing something here? Is there a way to use `UIGestureRecognizer`s on a per-node basis? Or, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you seen [the tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites) on Ray Wenderlich's site? It looks like a great place to start.

Comment: @Moshe, per my question, I need to be able to move *multiple* nodes *simultaneously*.

Comment: I realize this an 8 year-old question at this point, but did you ever get an answer to this question or figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and got really good help from @vacawama. Plesae see this link: [How to implement multiple PanGestures (Draggable views)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117094/how-to-implement-multiple-pangestures-draggable-views)

I this what you're looking for?

Comment: I appreciate the answer, @Kjetil, but no, you didn't have the same problem. You wanted to manipulate multiple `UIView`s, not multiple child nodes of an `SKScene`.

Comment: what about this: [link](http://asmeurer.github.io/blog/posts/playing-with-swift-and-spritekit/) ?

Comment: That's closer, @Kjetil, but still not what I need. I'm going to be handling lots of gestures, and dumping all of that logic into the `SKScene`s touch handling methods will turn into a mess very quickly. This is part of what I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: I see. Sorry, but can't help you. I'm very new to this and struggling to get the basics.. just found that link and thought it might help :-)

Comment: No worries--I appreciate the attempt.