# How can I change layout constraints for different views using a pan gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a function which adds a new `UIView` to the main view every time a button is pressed. I'd like for each of these views to be draggable. At the moment I'm doing this by adding a pan gesture recognizer to each view, which changes the layout constraints of each view.

My problem is, I'm not disabling the original constraint of each view correctly before it's moved, so the new and old constraints are clashing.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController5: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var textPosXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
var textPosYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

var numberOfViews = 0

var startingConstantPosX: CGFloat  = 0.0
var startingConstantPosY: CGFloat  = 100.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "edit views"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addView))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(clearThis))
}

@objc func addView() {

    let view1 = UIView()
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    view1.frame = CGRect()
    view.addSubview(view1)
    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

    textPosXConstraint = view1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
    textPosXConstraint.isActive = true

    textPosYConstraint = view1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
    textPosYConstraint.isActive = true

    numberOfViews+=1
    view1.tag = numberOfViews

    //add pan gesture
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    view1.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func clearThis() {
    for view in view.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    numberOfViews = 0
}

@objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let currentView = gestureRecognizer.view else { return }

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {

        print("view being moved is: \(currentView.tag)")

        startingConstantPosY = textPosYConstraint.constant
        startingConstantPosX = textPosXConstraint.constant

    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)

        let newXConstant = self.startingConstantPosX + translation.x
        let newYConstant = self.startingConstantPosY + translation.y

        currentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: startingConstantPosX).isActive = false
        currentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: newXConstant).isActive = true

    }
}
}
```

Ideally it will work so the user can add as many views as they'd like and move each one around.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the position constraints you create for a view so that you can either change their `constant` value or set `isActive = false` before creating new constraints.

1. Create a subclass of `UIView` called `MovableView` that has `NSLayoutConstraint?` properties for `horizontalConstraint` and `verticalConstraint`.
2. Set those properties when you create the constraints before setting their `isActive = true`.
3. When you need to move a `MovableView`, update the `constant` property for the `horizontalConstraint` and `verticalConstraint`.

   ```
   moveableView.horizontalConstraint?.constant = newXConstant
   moveableView.verticalConstraint?.constant = newYConstant
   ```

   Alternatively, you can set `horizontalConstraint?.isActive = false` and `verticalConstraint?.isActive = false` before creating, assigning, and activating the new constraints.

   ```
   moveableView.horizontalConstraint?.isActive = false
   moveableView.verticalConstraint?.isActive = false

   moveableView.horizontalConstraint = ...
   moveableView.horizontalConstraint?.isActive = true

   moveableView.verticalConstraint = ...
   moveableView.verticalConstraint?.isActive = true
   ```

See [draggable views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27139954/1630618) for an implementation of draggable views that I wrote 4 years ago.  It is out of date and needs updating, but you might get some ideas from it.  Also read the comments below it where @Matt explains that you can skip using constraints for a draggable view.  It is possible to add views to the screen that do not partake in *Auto Layout* even if the rest of the screen does.

---

I fixed your code:

- You didn't provide the implementation of `MovableView`, but it appears that the constraint properties were `static` instead of member properties.  You need them to be member properties in order to support multiple movable views.
- You had `startingConstantPosX` and `startingConstantPosY` swapped which is what caused the jumping.

---

```
class MovableView: UIView {
    var horizontalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var verticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var numberOfViews = 0

    var startingConstantPosX: CGFloat  = 0.0
    var startingConstantPosY: CGFloat  = 100.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "edit views"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addView))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(clearThis))
    }

    @objc func addView() {

        let view1 = MovableView()
        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        view1.frame = CGRect()
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true

        view1.horizontalConstraint = view1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
        view1.horizontalConstraint?.isActive = true

        view1.verticalConstraint = view1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
        view1.verticalConstraint?.isActive = true

        numberOfViews+=1
        view1.tag = numberOfViews

        //add pan gesture
        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        view1.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func clearThis() {
        for view in view.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        numberOfViews = 0
    }


    @objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        guard let currentView = gestureRecognizer.view as? MovableView else { return }

        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {

            print("view being moved is: \(currentView.tag)")

            startingConstantPosX = currentView.horizontalConstraint?.constant ?? 0
            startingConstantPosY = currentView.verticalConstraint?.constant ?? 0

        } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

            let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)

            let newXConstant = startingConstantPosX + translation.x
            let newYConstant = startingConstantPosY + translation.y

            currentView.horizontalConstraint?.constant = newXConstant
            currentView.verticalConstraint?.constant = newYConstant

        }

    }

}
```

---

If you set the `translation` back to `.zero` each time `handlePan` is called, you can simplify the code by not needing to keep track of the starting position:

```
@objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let currentView = gestureRecognizer.view as? MovableView else { return }

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {

        print("view being moved is: \(currentView.tag)")

    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)

        currentView.horizontalConstraint?.constant += translation.x
        currentView.verticalConstraint?.constant += translation.y

        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(.zero, in: self.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - i implemented it and it's going in the right direction, but i'm getting some odd behaviour when i try to drag a view for the second time, it flies off the screen. This is what i've got if you have any thoughts - https://pastebin.com/9r7dvApy - also i agree, it would be easier to skip auto layout, and i started with that at first, but these will ultimately be uitextviews which expand when you type into them, so i need the constraints for that. Thanks again :)

Comment: Wow this works great - thanks so much for the help! i really appreciate it! :)